# android studio - ndk where I can see error logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

why Android studio logcat does not show error logs ?

for example  : with this code ,  app just force stop and logcat just say "stack corruption detected"
I mean it must say "buf" has not enough space for "111" or something like that

```
char buf[2];
sprintf(buf, "%d", 111);
```

my current AS version is 2020.3.1

and I added log lib to my cmake but still no error show !

```
find_library(
        log-lib
        log )

target_link_libraries(
        ${log-lib}
)
```

Comment: If you're actually using the android logging functions somewhere, then you should see their output in the logcat output, same as with your Java logs. But it sounds to me like you're really talking about the stacktrace from a crash, which doesn't really have anything to do with the logging library. The stacktrace should also be found in the logcat output, but stacktraces from native crashes typically aren't very detailed when it comes to describing the reason for the crash.

Comment: If you compiled in the debug mode, you should at least be able to see the exact file, function and line number where the crash occurred. From there it's up to you to figure out _why_ it crashed at that line of code. You could also try looking into using additional tools like AddressSanitizer or Valgrind to get more detailed information about certain types of errors.